# No se actualizan los datos en Codeigniter

Tags: php, formularios, codeigniter, base-de-datos, codeigniter-3

Estoy utilizando una web que está desarrollada en Codeigniter.

El problema que tengo es al momento de agregar un servicio o cliente, ya que esta app es desarrollada para un sistema de servicio técnico para PCs. Al momento que agregas un cliente, te muestra un formulario con los datos. Lo agregas, pero no se refresca la lista de la página anterior y así pasa con todo: con servicios, órdenes de servicios, el index, etc.

Pero refrescando con <kbd>F5</kbd> ya refresca la lista de clientes, y así me sucede con todo: servicios, usuarios, órdenes, etc.

Les dejo el código del view de clientes:

```
<?php 
if ($this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'aCliente')) { 
?>

    <a href="<?php 
        echo base_url();
    ?>index.php/clientes/adicionar" class="btn btn-success">
        <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> 
        Agregar Cliente
    </a>

<?php
}
?>

<?php
if (!$results) {
?>

        <div class="widget-box">
        <div class="widget-title">
            <span class="icon">
                <i class="icon-user"></i>
            </span>
            <h5>Clientes</h5>

        </div>

        <div class="widget-content nopadding">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Cedula/RUC</th>
                        <th>Teléfono</th>
                        <th>Acción</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5">Ningún Cliente Registrado</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php 

}else{

?>

<div class="widget-box">
     <div class="widget-title">
        <span class="icon">
            <i class="icon-user"></i>
         </span>
        <h5>Clientes</h5>

     </div>

<div class="widget-content nopadding">


<table class="table table-bordered ">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Cedula/RUC</th>
            <th>Teléfono</th>
            <th>Acción</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($results as $r) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$r->idClientes.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$r->nomeCliente.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$r->documento.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$r->c_telefone.'</td>';
            echo '<td>';
            if($this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'vCliente')){
                echo '<a href="'.base_url().'index.php/clientes/visualizar/'.$r->idClientes.'" style="margin-right: 1%" class="btn tip-top" title="Ver mas detalles"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i></a>'; 
            }
            if($this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'eCliente')){
                echo '<a href="'.base_url().'index.php/clientes/editar/'.$r->idClientes.'" style="margin-right: 1%" class="btn btn-info tip-top" title="Editar Cliente"><i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i></a>'; 
            }
            if($this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'dCliente')){
                echo '<a href="#modal-excluir" role="button" data-toggle="modal" cliente="'.$r->idClientes.'" style="margin-right: 1%" class="btn btn-danger tip-top" title="Eliminar Cliente"><i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i></a>'; 
            }


            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }?>
        <tr>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links();}?>




<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modal-excluir" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <form action="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/clientes/excluir" method="post" >
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h5 id="myModalLabel">Eliminar Cliente</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <input type="hidden" id="idCliente" name="id" value="" />
    <h5 style="text-align: center">¿Realmente deseas eliminar este cliente y los datos asociados con él (O.S, ventas, ingresos)?</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancelar</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>






<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


   $(document).on('click', 'a', function(event) {

        var cliente = $(this).attr('cliente');
        $('#idCliente').val(cliente);

    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Hola @Carlos, no es una ayuda como tal, pero espero que mi comentario te sirva de algo, por lo que he visto en tu publicacion veo que estas usando php,html y javascript en un a sola vista y no es malo,pero te recomiendo que si estas usando el framework de codeigniter hagas uso de la arquitectura MVC para que tengas tu codigo un poco mas ordenado...asi podrás hacer algo como esto y puedo haber la posibilidad de que te funcione, como, que en tu vista cliente.php hagas el action al controller para insertar y se lo envies al modelo...

Comment: este siempre te devolverá un true o un false por lo que le puedes decir al controller, ok si se inserto bien los datos entonces header(Location:.....) sino muéstrame un mensaje...esa es una de muchas opciones...espero que este comentario sea de ayuda y lo tomes como una critica constructiva.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer estas ocupando el modal de bootstrap, lo que puedes hacer es que al finalizar el guardado y cierres el modal debes de refrescar la página automáticamente, esto lo puedes lograr con el siguiente código:

```
$("#modal").on('bs.hiden', function () {
    window.location.reload();
});
```

saludos

Comment: hola! lo he intentado antes de la etiqueta de cierre del div del modal pero no funciona , creo  que debe funcionar poniendo algo parecido pero en el header que se repite en todas las paginas y asi las refresque por que como comento esto me sucede con todas no solo con esta Gracias!!